# CI: использование buildNumber при разных пайплайнах

Tags: непрерывная-интеграция, release-management

При переводе проекта на "правильные рельсы" и внедрении CI/git-flow возникло следующее видение конфигурации:

- Есть пайплайн "next-release", который обслуживает непосредственно ветку develop. В случае успешного прохождения и принятия решения о релизе он генерирует новую ветку `release/$major.($minor + 1)` с версией формата `$major.($minor + 1).0.$buildNumber`
- Есть пайплайн "release-maintenance", который существует для валидации хотфиксов, попавших в релизные ветки и который генерирует версию `$major.$minor.($patch + 1).$buildNumber`

buildNumber, по фен-шую, должен указывать на конкретный запуск джобы, в которой сгенерировался релиз, чтобы можно было посмотреть логи в случае непредвиденных обстоятельств. В случае, если каждый пайплайн просто устанавливает свой номер запуска, получается неразбериха:

- next-release #1 -> v0.1.0.1
- next-release #2 -> v0.2.0.2
- release-maintenance #1 -> v0.2.1.1 // по patch > 0 можно понять, о каком пайплайне идет речь, но универсального идентификатора это не дает

В случае, если всегда используется номер пайплайна next-release, невозможно отследить конкретный билд current-release. Остаются еще два очевидных варианта: делать префикс/суффикс к buildNumber - будет получаться 0.1.0.n1, 0.2.0.n2, 0.2.1.c1 (но я такое видел всего пару раз, может быть) - и указывать оба buildNumber, но от этого варианта *пахнет*.

Как это принято делать в серьезных проектах?